# get html after jquery action

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates, append

Fairly new to jquery.

I've got a page setup where a user clicks buttons, which adds text content to div.

I then want to retrive the edited contents of this div and append another div at the bottom of the page with them.

I thought of using:

```
var divcontents = $('#firstdiv').html();
$('#targetDiv').append(divcontents);
```

However this doesn't work, because the contents of the first div were added by jquery actions, and are are not in the core HTML.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: i suppose you are populating #firstdiv via AJAX? Cant you just add response from AJAX to varaible and use that, or am I missing something?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/mxnR6/ is this what you are doing? then it is working. how are you adding contents to first div?

Comment: Hi no not using AJAX (not sure how!).  #firstdiv is populated using another 'append' function from another div on the page.  User clicks a button, and it take the contents of that div and appends it to #firstdiv

Comment: In context, this is a sort of shopping basket. User adds item to basket, then presses continue.  when he/she presses continue, it appends a form at the bottom of the page with the contents of the basket

Comment: @user2226032 you need to set up a fiddle or provide more code. what i put in the comments in simple is working fine.

Comment: Your code should work if #firstdiv have data..!!! if not jQuey file is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are desynchronized on events executions or your 'firstdiv' is not appended to body. I made this example and works for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/FsrYS/

```
<div id="targetDiv" style="background-color: red">Target</div>

jQuery(function($) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.id = 'firstdiv';
    newDiv.innerHTML = 'FirstDiv';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(newDiv);
    var divcontents = $('#firstdiv').html();
    $('#targetDiv').append(divcontents);
});
```